# Why is my array not working?

Tags: java, arrays

Can someone please help me with this project I need to do

```
public class ArrayPrinter {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] oneD = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    printArray(oneD); 
    System.out.println(); 
    System.out.println("\n"); 

}
public static void printArray(int[][] arr) {
     System.out.print("["); 

     int[][] twoD = {{ 2, 4, 6, 8 },
                    {8, 7, 9, 1},
                    {3, 5, 1, 2}};

     printArray(twoD); 
     System.out.println(); //4
     System.out.println("\n"); 


     int rows = 3;
     int columns = 4;
     int i, j;

     for (i=0; i < rows ; i++) {
         for (j=0; j < columns ; j++) {
             System.out.print( aryNumbers[i] [j] + " ");
         }

        System.out   
     }

     System.out.println("]"); 
}
}

public static final void printArray(int[] arr) {
    System.out.print("["); 
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
        if (i == arr.length - 1) 
            System.out.print(arr[i]);
        else
            System.out.print(arr[i] + ", "); 
    }
    System.out.println("]"); 
}

}
```

nothing is working, and i dont understand why. I have been doing this for 6 hours now and I feel so dumb. I dont get anything at all. Why is the in [][] twoD ={{ 2, 4, 6, 8 },
                                                                   {8, 7, 9, 1},
                                                                   {3, 5, 1, 2}};
not posting

Comment: You have an infinite loop. `printArray()` is calling itself over and over without modification of data. OK, not really an infinite loop, but a bottomless recursion.

Comment: So what does that I have to do?

Comment: Depends. What are you *trying* to do?

Comment: Ok, I was just going to show you what I was trying to do, sorry

Comment: Just describe it here. Modify your original post to tell what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: @quinnyb I would remove your email comment... unless you want spam.

Comment: Why are you passing an `int[]` to a method that takes an `int[][]`?

Comment: I dont think that your code even compile.. where do you declare the variable `aryNumbers`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch The example is longer one page in it's frame. Scroll down on the code to see the whole example

Comment: @NickRoth I know, but OP's last sentence is *Why is the in [][] twoD ={{ 2, 4, 6, 8 }, {8, 7, 9, 1}, {3, 5, 1, 2}}; not posting* and the answer appears to be that OP is calling the other method.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I must have misunderstood the intent of your comment then. Figured other people might have missed the extra code too since I almost did :)

Comment: I don't even know where to start, I'm so lost on everything :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you don't ever call the `printArray(int[][] arr)` method. In `main` you call `printArray(int[] arr)` which does its thing then returns. If you don't understand why it's not calling the `int[][]` version, take some time to learn about method overloading in Java.

Answer (score 1):

*First you should know that what is Function Overloading?*

> The Java programming language supports overloading methods, and Java
>   can distinguish between methods with different method signatures. This
>   means that methods within a class can have the same name if they have
>   different parameter lists.

Two functions in a class with same name but different type of parameters or different number of parameters result in function overloading.

**For example:**

```
class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        f1(2);//this will print Int function on screen
        f1(2.5);//this will print Double function on screen
    }

    public static void f1(int a){
        //do something
        System.out.println("Int function");
    }
    public static void f1(double a){
        //do something else
        System.out.println("Double function");
    }

}
```

Similarly in your code you are having two functions with same name

> printArray(parameter)

But in both functions parameters are different. One is receiving 1D array and other one is receiving 2D array. So if you want to hit printArray(1D) then just make a 1D array and pass it in parameters. But if you want to hit printArray(2D) then first make a 2D array and then pass that 2D array to printArray function. Then other function will be invoked.

Hope you understand what you are missing.

If you understood what's the problem. Then following is your code in which I have done some modification. But PLEASE first clear the concept and then go to actual coding.

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] oneD = { 5, 6, 7, 8 };
        printArray(oneD); 
        System.out.println(); 
        System.out.println("\n"); 

        int[][] twoD = {{ 2, 4, 6, 8 },
                {8, 7, 9, 1},
                {3, 5, 1, 2}};

        printArray(twoD); 


    }
    public static void printArray(int[][] arr) {
        System.out.println("["); 



        int rows = 3;
        int columns = 4;
        int i, j;

        for (i=0; i < rows ; i++) {
            for (j=0; j < columns ; j++) {
                System.out.print( arr[i] [j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("]"); 
    }


    public static final void printArray(int[] arr) {
        System.out.print("["); 
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) { 
            if (i == arr.length - 1) 
                System.out.print(arr[i]);
            else
                System.out.print(arr[i] + ", "); 
        }
        System.out.println("]"); 
    }

}
```

Comment: it makes so much sense now, what happens if i have three arrays and the last two both are  public static void printArray(int[][] arr)

Comment: public static void printArray(int[][] arr) is a function not an array. Unable to understand what you want to ask.

Comment: sorry I meant 3 functions, last two with the same name

Comment: Try to have it and compile your code and then tell me what happened?

Comment: [5, 6, 7, 8]





[
2,4,6,8,
8,7,9,1,
3,5,1,2,
]
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at ArrayPrinter.main(ArrayPrinter.java:16)

Answer (score 0):

First of all your program has some syntax errors and second you have only called 'printArray(oneD);' in the PSVM() method, that's why it's not called the twoD. Please try to correct the program and try again.